# Easy way to set text style across documents

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, layer-style, paragraph-styles

Sometimes when I click a color with the eye dropper in Photoshop CS 6, the color of a text layer in my document will change to that color. Oddly enough, this happens only one and I cannot duplicate it. I do not know how/why that happens and would love to know.

To the more pressing matter at hand: After I have designed a text layer the way I want it, I wish to use the same style on a series of other documents, I have not found anything, short of duplicating the text layer and retyping the text, that would accomplish that and I would like to ask for help with that.
I wish for a text layer in another document to have the same font, size, color etc. as the one in the current document. How pls?

I believe text styles do not transfer across documents for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

Text styles do not transfer across documents, simply because they are different documents. An easy way to achieve this is to color your text layer via **layer style** (color overlay) and then **copy the layer style** to a different layer in a different document.

Comment: Yes, this would work, however is there any trick to pass/set text font and size from document to document?